# Can I know about the location of the .txt file in "context.openFileInput("txt")"

Tags: android

I created a java class and I wanted to read a text file.

I used below code to read the .txt file but I could not understand .txt file's location.

```
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput(".txt");
        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new 
            InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            this.buildDictionary(reader);
            inputStream.close();
            inputStreamReader.close();
            reader.close();

        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
}
```

I made folder and named as 'folder' in 'com.example.myapplication' but still there was an 'File Not Found' exception.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `/data/user/0/{your.package.name}/files/.txt`.

I will suggest you use the following in your code to get the files directory.

```
context.getFilesDir()
```

Answer (score 0):

File file = new File("test.txt");

System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

Output:
I/System.out: /test.txt

It is in root.